# Add List<string> to DataGridView Rows

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am new to using the DataGridView component, I've used it once before and have managed to complete this exact task but I forgot how I achieved it.

Basically I would like to read the values from a text file which is formatted like so:

`line 1,
line 2,
line 3`

Here is the code I currently have:

```
List<string> tokens = new List<string>();
private void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] lines = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.GetFullPath(line)))
        {
            var l = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] data;
            while (l != null)
            {
                data = l.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                l = sr.ReadLine();
                tokens.Add(l);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Selected = true;
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = tokens[i];
    }
}
```

The current code results in the `line 2` being added to the datagridview only, with nothing else.
I would like to add each line into the first column of each row, depending on how many lines are in the text file.

Hopefully this makes sense, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
private void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Value", "Value");
  var files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
  foreach ( var file in files )
  {
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path.GetFullPath(file));
    foreach ( string line in lines )
      dataGridView1.Rows.Add(line.TrimEnd(','));
  }
}

private void dataGridView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  if ( e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) )
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
  else
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}
```

Comment: Amazing! This works perfectly, thank you very much! :)